# How to convert ULONG64 to PCSTR?

Tags: c++

I am quite new to C++, because I normally use C#.

Here is the code I am currently using (although I have tried plenty of other things):

```
template <class T>
inline PCSTR to_string (const T& t)
{
std::stringstream ss;
ss << t;
return ss.str().c_str();
}



ULONG bugCheckCode = 0;
ULONG64 bugCheckArgs[4] = {0};
Control->ReadBugCheckData(&bugCheckCode, &bugCheckArgs[0], &bugCheckArgs[1], &bugCheckArgs[2], &bugCheckArgs[3]);

CHAR arg2[sizeof(bugCheckArgs[1])];
ZeroMemory(arg2, sizeof(bugCheckArgs[1]));

memcpy(arg2, &bugCheckArgs[1], sizeof(bugCheckArgs[1]));

Control->CallExtension(NULL, "function", arg2);
```

Basically, ReadBugCheckData returns a PULONG64, which I give an address to a ULONG64. I am pretty sure that this bit is alright, but since I am new to all this memory stuff, I shall post it just in case the mistake lies here.

So I now have a ULONG64 (typedef unsigned long long ULONG64) which I need to convert to a PCSTR (typedef CONST CHAR *PCSTR), which, if I understand correctly, is a char array??? So I tried the to_string function posted at the top of the code snippet, and I tried memcpy, but I can't get it to work.

But all I can get is nothingness or junk data. I am finding this particularly difficult to debug because this is an extension, and I can't step through the code properly.

Any ideas on how to do this conversion?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: inline on a template is useless. The compiler will decide what to inline, and templates don't suffer from regular functions' multiple definition problem.

Comment: another user on SO chat has informed me that function template specializations in headers will need the inline (to avoid the multiple definition problem), so it's as not *completely* useless as a form of style to prevent such errors, which might be unexpected when writing a template specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
template <class T>
inline PCSTR to_string (const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str().c_str();
}
```

returns a pointer to memory that is owned by a temporary returned by `str()` and thus getting destroyed as soon the the functions exits. Instead use:

```
template <class T>
inline std::string to_string (const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}
```

And at the call site retrieve the `const char*` as:

```
CallSomething(to_string(x).c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Very greatly appreciated. Well, that made it a lot better, but there is still one small problem :p. The value I put into the ULONG64 was in hexadecimal: 8572a01c. I used your code, and got out this: 184467440716534661401. So I converted to hexadecial, and got out FFFFFFFF8572A000. Trim off the beginning: 8572A000. The final two or three digits have been zeroed out. Any idea why that happened? Thank you so much again for all your help!

Comment: @niemiro: you somewhere in the process worked with 32-bit signed integers, so it got sign extended. I can't provide more info based on the code pasted in the question. How did you initialize the ULONG64?

Comment: @niemiro: also `184467440716534661401` is `FFFFFFFB367A4119` in hexadecimal. I think your conversions are wrong too.

Comment: I gave you the wrong number. Sorry about that. The number I actually get out of the program is 18446744071653466140 (I added an extra 1 onto the end). This correct number does come to FFFFFFFB367A4119. Good spot, and my appologies. Now that my human error has been eliminated, do you have any other ideas? The ULONG64 I am using is bugCheckArgs[1], which you can see initialised with "={0}" in the above code snippet, and it is filled with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553517(v=vs.85).aspx as seen in the code snippet. I am then printing the result with

Comment: "to_string(bugCheckArgs[1]).c_str()" as seen in the code snippet. I am doing nothing else at all. The code snippet is not oversimplified. Do you have any more ideas? Thank you so very much for all you help thus far.

Comment: @niemiro: you said "value I put into the ULONG64 was in hexadecimal: 8572a01c." My question was where did you specify that value? I'm not familiar with `ReadBugCheckData` and it doesn't say what value it writes there. What makes you think it's incorrect?

Comment: Fixed it! Basically, this is an extension for WinDBG. ReadBugCheckData reads the BSoD bugcheck code and parameters. If I look at the analyze -v output, I can tell what it is supposed to be. I have spent hours trying to figure this out, and that involved loads of different techniques, including the one in the other answer. But they all came out with that same number, which when converted to hex zeroed out the last three digits. This is the code which worked in the end: char c[17]; sprintf(c, "%llX", bugCheckArgs[1]); However, if I change the modifier to %llu, I get a dec representation of the

Comment: hex number with the last two zeroed out again. Madness! No idea why! But if I ask for it in hex, all is well. Let's not even go there. lol. There is one other part of the story. Because this is a kernal minidump, the length of the parameters is either 64bit or 32bit, depending on bit number of the OS. lol. I am marking this as the answer because you have been so very helpful. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at these functions:
[Conversion functions Visual C++ Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt.aspx)
for secure version:
[Conversions functions CRT_SECURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h.aspx)
scroll down to bottom of box, look for...

radix means numerical base (10 for common, 2 for binary, 16 for hexadeciamlic system)

```
char * _ui64toa(
   unsigned _int64 value,
   char (&str)[size],
   int radix 
); // C++ only

errno_t _i64toa_s(
   __int64 value,
   char *buffer,
   size_t sizeInCharacters,
   int radix
```